# How I can change the URL that is redirecting to Item_CommonItem_Body?

Tags: search, search-results, display-template

How I can change the URL that is redirecting to `Item_CommonItem_Body` from the method `#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#` in Item_Default of Display Template of the search in Sharepoint Online?

I use copy and paste the content in `Item_Default` at the moment, but I don´t think that this is a good method to do it.

Edit: I use a copy of "Item_Default.html" and I do the same with "Item_CommonItem_Body.html". I want to know if exist a way to redirect the display template that calls `#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Short of changing the JS you can't. Tell us what problem you face and let's see if you are trying to solve it the right way. It sounds like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I do a copy of "Item_Default.html" to change the title what is displaying in this templeate with a custom variable. I select this templeate but i dont want to delete #=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=# with a custom html display. I want to use this method with a copy of "Item_CommonItem_Body", but i don´t know how i can redirect to this template using this method or same.

Comment: You would have to create an override of the method or create your own. Why do you need to change the result URL?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott In my case I want to make changes to the `Item_CommonItem_Body` template but I don't want this change to affect all other display templates. So I'm looking for a way I can copy that template and have my parent display template point to this new `commonitem_body`

Comment: Make a copy in your own file and rename the function.

Comment: did you get the solution for this issue. thanks,
ajay